# Variable which is recalling earlier defined variable in loop by number

Tags: bash

I'm searching for an answer for few hours and now I'm completely stuck.
I want to write a script, which will be automatically downloading files from seedbox, changing the filenames to "S0xE0x"format and then move it to the correct folder via smb and admin share. I'm using VM with Debian and Windows 10 as main OS.

Let's say, that I'm watching 10 series.

Here are variables for each of it (this part will be editable in future)

```
N1="Alice to Zouroku"
D1="Alice to Zouroku"
S1="01"
```

Where

- N1 is a name of the series
- D1 is a folder name
- S1 is a number of the season

I will skip the part with extracting episode numer from filename, because this is working fine.

After all variables I have another variable which is indicating amount of series (limit of the loop)

```
amount=12
```

and

```
serienumber=1
```

which is increasing by 1 in loop

so, this is my loop

```
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= $amount;  i++  ))do
    - name change part with $epname -
    - here is a part which is nor working -
    $serienumber++
done
```

So, what I want to do. I want to use defined variables which are called by $serienumber. 
For example:

```
mv $epname /mnt/anime/[variable D1 -> D$serienumber]/[variable S1 ->S$serienumber]E$epnum.mkv
```

How can I do this? How can I echo a variable with current loop number ($serienumber).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably be better off using a arrays here:

```
N[0]="Alice to Zouroku"
D[0]="Alice to Zouroku"
S[1]="01"
```

The increment `serienumber` (Should that be "seriesnumber" -- with an "s" in the middle?)

```
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= $amount;  i++  ))do
    (( serienumber++ ))
    echo $serienumber
done
```

Now, you can do your move de-referencing the arrays like this:

```
mv $epname /mnt/anime/D${D[serienumber]}]/S${S[serienumber]}E${epnum}.mkv
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't use arrays in the first place.